# how to use a value from TextBox(Platform::String) as Integer in UWP C++?

Tags: c++, uwp

I've created a text box in the xaml page that will receive some number.
And I want to use this number for some calculation.
So How can I  use the value from the Text Box as an Integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following.

```
#include <sstream>

String^ str_input = textBox->Text; //get Platform::String from textBox
std::wstring wsstr(str_input->Data());//Convert Platform::String to String
int n = std::stoi(wsstr);//Convert String to Int
```